# ROS Answers SE migration: Real ros root

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS_ROOT doesn't point to the root of a ros installation (i.e. where setup.sh, the base binaries, base libs reside), but I'm looking for installation root for use with a release script I'm writing.

Is there a way to figure this out programmatically? I know for example in fuerte I could simply figure out what the relative path is and adjust, but it's different for previous versions, and I'd like to use a sanctioned way to avoid edge cases/be future-proof.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39686/real-ros-root/) by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2743 on 2012-07-24

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Future releases of ROS will try to move away from the concept of a ROS_ROOT to be FHS compliant, meaning users will be able to install ROS like other other software into e.g. /usr/local/. So there will not be any ROS_ROOT anymore in the future. To be future-proof, do not assume that a ROS_ROOT exists, even in concept.

You can see these REPs for this:

http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0122.html

http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0123.html

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2012-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3